# Xamarin Forms List View doesn't display added items instantly with Observable Collection

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, system.reactive, observablecollection, reactiveui

I'm trying to verify if ListView displays or refreshes items instantly whenever we add an object to the Observable Collection, but it doesn't. I have tested in Debugging mode in Visual Studio, and ListView only displays items once all the objects have been iterated and added to the Observable Collection (for e.g. in the below Subscribe method). What am I missing?

Note: I've also applied INotifyPropertyChanged both on underlying Model and ViewModel (Page1 in this example) so that ListView can listen to property changed event of collection as well, but no luck.

Here's the code example:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        ObservableCollection<TestModel> trackListObservable;
        public ObservableCollection<TestModel> Items
        {
            get { return trackListObservable; }
            set
            {
                trackListObservable = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TrackListObservable"));
                }
            }
        }

        public Page1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            Items = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>();
            BindingContext = Items;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            List<int> test = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

            test.ToObservable()
                .SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => Increment(x)))
                .Select(x => x)
                .Subscribe(result => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    Items.Add(new TestModel() { Number = result });
                }));
        }

        int Increment(int num)
        {
            return num++;
        }
    }

    public class TestModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int number;

        public int Number
        {
            get { return number; }
            set
            {
                number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Number));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

    }
```

XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinApp.Page1"
             x:Name="testpage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="testlist" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding BindingContext, Source={x:Reference testpage}}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <Label Text="Loading Blog..." HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Add a `Task.Delay` after your `Items.Add` so you can "visualize" that the UI is being updated properly upon each add (it is happening so fast that the ui refresh of around 16ms is long enough to hide the 5 individual adds on the main thread)

Comment: Your PropertyChangedEventArgs has a value of `TrackListObservable` but your property name is `Items`. Use the nameof() operator

Comment: What's the point of your `test.ToObservable()` section of code? It doesn't seem to do anything special that relates to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried Task.Delay but no change. It still displays items after all the items get added to the collection.

Comment: @GlennWatson: I corrected that in the code which fixed my another problem getting at binding related to casting. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @Enigmativity: The point of using `test.ToObservable()` is that I'm making it Observable to increment each number by 1 and at the same time subscribing it to add it to the Observable Collection and at the same time would like to reflect or display this added item under ListView of Xamarin forms.  This is just a prototype code and I'm trying to achieve reactivity with list view here using Observable Collection. Please let me know if any improvement here.

Comment: @DurgeshKhandal - Yes, I understand what the code is doing. I asked what the point of it was. I asked about the `test.ToObservable` **section of code**.

Comment: There are a lot of things in this question that i do not understand and would love it if you clarified

Comment: The `ToObservable` section seems to be redundant. `ToObservable` will take the elements of your `List<T>` and create an observable out of them (it won't update on new objects being added or anything like that). If you need automatic updating lists look into DynamicData https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData -- as it is now it's not very useful what you got there and you might as well be doing `Select` statements without the `ToObservable`

Comment: You can tidy up your code structure and separate the model from the view. Then you can try to change the `ItemsSource="{Binding BindingContext, Source={x:Reference testpage}}"` to bind the `testlist.ItemsSource = Items;` in the page.

Comment: @Enigmativity @Glenn Watson - The reason I used `ToObservable` is to convert the action on the elements of collection (List) to an observable and immediately subscribe to it. For e.g. whenever the single element is incremented in the loop of Select Many, i want to subscribe to it immediately and add it to the observable collection which should further notify the ListView about its collection changed event. And then, ListView should display this item immediately.
I referred to this previous answer for creating observable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54602529

Comment: @GlennWatson Thanks for referring to Dynamic Data. I will look into this as I got to know that ReactiveList has been deprecated. But before I use Dynamic Data, I just wanted to try it with Observable Collection (as it also implements INotifyPropertyChanged) which according to its definition should notify the ListView.

Comment: @DurgeshKhandal - Only the first `@` per comment actually notifies - subsequent ones do not.

Comment: @DurgeshKhandal - The only thing that the observable does is push the sequence on to another thread, but it tries to run as fast as possible. You're probably better off using `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Take(5)` to get behaviour that is humanly observable (pardon the pun).